# sonarqube api/permission/add_group for project permission managenebt

Tags: sonarqube

Please advice what I did wrong with this api call for Sonarqube.

=> To give grp1 with issueadmin permission for myproj, I ran the command below

1. curl -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://localhost:9000/api/permissions/add_group?projectkey=mykey;groupId=4;permission=issueadmin'

---

```
  {"errors":[{"msg":"The 'permission' parameter for global permissions 
must be one of admin, profileadmin, gateadmin, shareDashboard, scan, 
provisioning. 'issueadmin' was passed."}]}
```

2. curl -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://localhost:9000/api/permissions/add_group?projectkey=myproj;groupId=4;permission=issueadmin'

---

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"The 'permission' parameter for global permissions must be 
one of admin, profileadmin, gateadmin, shareDashboard, scan, provisioning.
 'issueadmin' was passed."}]}
```

groupid = 4;

groupname = grp1

project name = myproj;

project id = 4;

project key = mykey

Comment: I tested on version 5.5 and version 6

Answer (score 3):

Check out `api/permissions/add_group` documentation ([here](http://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/permissions/add_group)) . The error messages you get talks about **global** permissions, so somehow the project key hasn't been interpreted correctly. Looking closer at the parameters:

> *projectKey* - optional - Project key

So typo it is. You've used `projectkey` instead of `projectKey`.

But then there's another problem in your URL: you're using `;` to separate parameters, instead of the standard `&`. All in all, this should do the trick:

> curl -u admin:admin -X POST 'http://localhost:9000/api/permissions/add_group?projectKey=mykey&groupId=4&permission=issueadmin'